# Displaying Microsoft Exchange Server attachment in PHP

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I've searched stackoverflow and haven't found anything quite like what I'm having trouble with. I have a .NET app that is pulling data from Microsoft Exchange Server and feeding it into a PHP app via a curl request. I can read the e-mail just fine, and I can retrieve attachment data just fine (or so I think). The problem is that the attachment data doesn't seem usable. It comes in the following format:

```
{"<string #1>":
    {"Content":"<very, very long string>",
     "ContentId":null,
     "ContentLocation":null,
     "ContentType":null,
     "Id":"<string #1 repeated>",
     "Name":"Picture (Device Independent Bitmap)",
     "Filename:"null
    }
}
```

This is just one example. I have a few that are jpegs, pdfs, etc. ContentID, ContentLocation, ContentType, and Filename are always null, probably due to the ancient version of Exchange being run. Content is a string that can easily be several hundred thousand characters long. I've tried displaying it in an image tag, and I've tried base64_decoding it, but it only ever comes up with garbage. Decoders online have only come up with garbage as well. What data do I need to use to display this image? Or is there a specific set of manipulations I need to do on the string to get it to be human-readable?

I'd be happy to include the string, but as I said: it's a very lengthy string.

Comment: This could also be caused by the annoying fact that as always MS-Exchange does _not_ completely follow the standards for protocols and formats, but took care to implement things slightly different than everyone else. I spent endless time trying to get things work identical with MS-Exchange and any other standards compliant IMAP server. So my hint: do not invest too much time into this...

Comment: @arkascha Haha, "I'm not saying it's impossible, but..." I'll take that advice under consideration. If I don't get a solution soon, I'll find a plan b.

Comment: Could it be the TNF (Transport Neutral Encapsulation) Format File? By the way why aren´t you fetching the attachments/emails via IMAP or POP3?

Comment: I'm fetching archived e-mail to/from multiple accounts. I didn't write this particular .NET app (a freelancer did), so I don't know if IMAP or POP3 were viable for that purpose. I'll look into TNF and report back.

Comment: @BastianW Pulling up the raw data from the .NET application indicates that the content is coming through as a byte string with values ranging from 0-255. In my very limited knowledge of the subject, that seems like a good clue that I'm dealing with TNF, since 0-127 is the RFC standard, does it not?

Comment: Yes that's what I´m thinking as well (by the way its TNEF, i missed the "e"). As you said you are fetching the content with cURL you might save that and try to open that with an winmail.dat converter. If you get some content you need then a way how to convert the TNEF content you have.